# Laravel 5.6 passport api authentication not working in get request

Tags: php, laravel, api

I am making single page application and while processing get request, i have passed `X-CSRF-TOKEN` and `X-Requested-With` headers.I also have included  `\Laravel\Passport\Http\Middleware\CreateFreshApiToken::class` in web middleware group.
my route in api.php looks like

```
Route::get('categories','Api\Categories@index')->middleware('auth:api');
```

but requesting specified url shows unauthenticated message.

Comment: Did you create get request with authentication param?

Comment: Did you set the API auth driver to `passport` in your `config/auth.php` file?

Comment: Sent Authorization header 'Bearer {token}

Comment: Is there something in the provided answer that you believe does not address your question? If so then please comment on the answer to clarify what exactly needs to be addressed that has not. If it resolved your problem then [Accept  Answers](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work)

Answer (score 4):

I got the exact same problem a while ago. And this is what I've done to fix it, more details in this post: https://github.com/laravel/passport/issues/47

So this is normally to fix the oAuth Client tokens: The expiry date is set to now + 100 years in Passport.php, line 167.

```
return static::$tokensExpireAt? Carbon::now()->diff(static::$tokensExpireAt): new DateInterval('P100Y');
```

If you set it to, i.e., P1Y, it is working. Something like:

```
return static::$tokensExpireAt? Carbon::now()->diff(static::$tokensExpireAt): new DateInterval('P1Y');
```

The same holds true for the refresh token a few lines below:

```
return static::$refreshTokensExpireAt? Carbon::now()->diff(static::$refreshTokensExpireAt): new DateInterval('P1Y');
```

And this is for the Personal Tokens: And also in PassportServiceProvider.php line 84, concerning the Personal Tokens:

```
$server->enableGrantType(new PersonalAccessGrant, new DateInterval('P1Y'));

Hope it helps ! :)
```

Answer (score 3):

Send authorisation header in the request

```
Authorization: Bearer eYz-your-passport-generated-token
```